# C# paint to window faster than Graphics draw

Tags: c#, wpf, image, video

I have a WPF window with an image on it. I want to change the image quickly, like I were playing a video. Assuming that I have all the data in memory, is there a faster way to paint on a window than the following:

```
public void updateCanvas(byte[] imageData, RECT bounds)
    {
        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(imageData);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(canvas);
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, bounds.left, bounds.top);
        this.Image.Source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(canvas.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        this.Image.InvalidateVisual();
    }
```

Like is there a way just to store a pointer to the rendered byte data and do a byte copy? or a faster way to draw on a window (like maybe DirectX)?

The data is generated, so I can't just play a video file.

Thanks!

Comment: It's better idea to not recreate bitmap for every frame, but to reuse one instance. So if you can change the code that generates images, it's a good idea to do it. However, even better idea is to actually measure performance and to check if it's good enough. If it is, just don't bother.

Comment: the first problem you will encounter is that you cant just replace one bitmap with another to get performance as if it were a video (or anything close) videos are encoded using very complex algorithms so that only frames that have differences in them are stored, and so that only sections of the frame that are changing are updated. they are compressed in advance of their use because it generally cant be done in real time. the best you will do is something like an animated gif, which is a glorified slide show. If you intend to animate with uncompressed bitmaps id look into doublebuffering.

Comment: but it wont get you very far in terms of framrate. Using directx filters you can create a video from your bitmaps, but it will not be generated on the fly. If you want to produce a real time animation on the screen you might want to look at opengl or directx - but not using bitmaps. read the above as a single post pls.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be faster, but I have used `WriteableBitmap` for a similar purpose. It has a `BackBuffer`, to whose `Handle` you have access - meaning you can transfer bytes to it.

Comment: This approach will not take you anywhere. If you need a Video, why not  just put a Video? I don't understand. Otherwise if you need animations, WPF has built in support for them, and WPF vector graphics are much better and scalable than bitmap stuff. I strongly suggest you reconsider your approach, due to all the reasons @JohnFaulkner described above.

Comment: `data is generated` - Generated from where? by what? by your own code?  If that is the case, I strongly suggest you use the same data to draw vector graphics instead of bitmaps, using the WPF mechanisms and probably data binding.